# Webpack is ignoring the exclude directive I have in my webpack.config.js file

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

I upgraded **webpack** from **3** to the latest version **5**.

When running `npm run webpack`, I am getting a bunch of errors I never got in the old version.

They all seem to do with packages in my `node_modules` folder. Here's an example:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@material-ui/core/esm/ButtonBase/TouchRipple.js 6:0-57
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-transition-group' in 'G:\GamerRepo\ClientPortal\node_modules\@material-ui\core\esm\ButtonBase'
 @ ./node_modules/@material-ui/core/esm/ButtonBase/ButtonBase.js 13:0-40 322:22-33
```

Here is my project folder structure:

```
/GamerRepo
   /wwwroot
      /dist
   /ClientPortal
      /static
   /node_modules
```

In my `webpack.config.js`, I have it set to ignore two folders, `static` and `node_modules` inside my `ClientPortal` folder as seen here:

```
module: {

const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

let config = {
    mode: 'development',

    resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'ClientPortal'),
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'ClientPortal/static'),
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
        ],
        alias: {
            moment$: 'moment/moment.js'
        }
    },

    entry: {
        app: path.resolve(__dirname, 'ClientPortal/entryPoint.js'),
    },

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/dist'),
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].js'
    },
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, "ClientPortal"),
                exclude: /(ClientPortal\/static|node_modules)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env", '@babel/preset-react'],
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot)$/,
                type: 'asset/resource'
            },
        ]
    },
     plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin([__dirname + '/wwwroot/dist'], {
            root: process.cwd(),
            verbose: false
        }),

        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
        }),

        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /en/),
    ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

This used to work fine in version 3.  Is there anything I need to do with version 5?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have something related to material ui in `static` folder?

Comment: @yousoumar No, it's just a folder for some jquery stuff.  I do have `material-ui` stuff in the `node_modules` folder.

Comment: Try changing this `exclude: /(ClientPortal\/static|node_modules)/,` with `exclude: /node_modules/,` to know if the exclude is the problem.

Comment: @yousoumar I just made the change, rebuilt, and ran `npm run weback` from the command line and it is still giving me the same errors regarding `node_modules`

Comment: @yousoumar I just thought of something.  My `webpack.config.js`  and `node_modules` folder is in `G:\GamerRepo\`` .   But I run the command `npm run weback` in my `G:\GamerRepo\wwwroot\dist` folder.  Could that be why?

Comment: Yeah, this wouldn't work actually. You should run `npm run webpack` in the directory where `webpack.config.js` is.

Comment: @yousoumar But my project has always used `G:\GamerRepo\wwwroot\dist` where webpack generates all the .js files.  Is there a way to tell webpack to generate those files in `G:\GamerRepo\wwwroot\dist` if I run it in `G:\GamerRepo\``?

Comment: About what I said just before, it depends actually on `npm run weback`, is that  calls some script that indicates where to find `webpack.config.js`?

Comment: For me it seems to be either a directory issue, or you didn't install some dependencies.

Comment: @yousoumar that's the odd thing I guess, I have always ran `npm run weback` in `G:\GamerRepo\wwwroot\dist` and `G:\GamerRepo` is where `node_modules` and `webpack.config.js` lives.  I even tested it by introducing a typo in `webpack.config.js`, and running `npm run weback` in `G:\GamerRepo\wwwroot\dist` and sure enough, it sees the typo immediately and displays a big error in red.

Comment: I see. Maybe for a better idea, you could edit your question, add the hole config of webpack, and your project folder structure.

Comment: @yousoumar thanks, I should've included all that.

Answer (score 0):

I usually don't like answering my own question, but I found information that I hope helps others dealing with my situation.

All I had to do is tell `Webpack` a relative directory where `node_modules` lives.

So I added this to my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
resolve: {
    modules: [
'.', 'node_modules'
```

Apparently that is all it needed!  My errors went down from 123 to 1!